# Why this form of Lorentz force law in Gaussian units?

Tags: electromagnetism, units, si-units

In Ashcroft and Mermin's first chapter, equation (1.13), they write the Lorentz force law as (due only to a magnetic field)
$$\textbf{F} = \frac{-e}{c} \textbf{v} \times \textbf{H}$$
rather than as
$$\textbf{F} = \frac{-e}{c} \textbf{v} \times \textbf{B}$$
as I would have expected in Gaussian units. Why is this? I don't think that $\textbf{B} = \textbf{H}$ in Gaussian?

Comment: If you look directly on the page for gaussian units they will only be the same if there is no magnetization which is likely the assumption here.

Comment: @Triatticus I suppose that's an assumption which is a bit odd in an arbitrary material though no? Even in a metal?

Comment: It will certainly depend on the magnetic suceptibility of the material, and I don't personally own that book so I don't have the actual context.

Comment: @Triatticus Oy, I forgot most materials were nonmagnetic and was confusing with the dielectric case. Thanks for clarifying. If you supply an official answer I'd be happy to give it a green check. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mauricio Can you please provide a reference for that? I checked my textbooks and can't find that statement anywhere.

Comment: Sorry my statement was wrong, see Eq. 14a in here arxiv.org/abs/1312.3383 for Lorentz force in media. In the case where $\mathbf M=0$ and no electric fields, in gaussian units you have $\mathbf B=\mathbf H$ so you get the formula above.

Comment: @Mauricio I see, so you agree with Triatticus above who said $\textbf{M} = 0$ is here being assumed by the authors?

Answer (score 0):

$H$ does equal $B$ in Gaussian units. Their units are given different names to honor two physicists.  In any event, any force law is better written in terms of $B$, even when $H$ is equal to $B$ in magnitude. If $\mu$ does not equal 1, then the force should not be given in terms of $H$.

Comment: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units#Dielectric_and_magnetic_materials) does not agree with you (see the extra term including $\textbf{M}$ in the table).

Comment: I interpreted the question to be in free space where M=0.  In my last sentence, when $\mu$ does not equal one, M will not equal zero, H will not equal B, and should not be used in the force equation.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the $\mathbf B$ and the $\mathbf H$ field is given in gaussian-cgs units as
$$\mathbf B=\mathbf H+4\pi \mathbf M$$
where $\mathbf M$ is the magnetization. In the case where $\mathbf M=0$, we have $\mathbf B =\mathbf H$, so we write the Lorentz force (in the absence of electric field $\mathbf E$ and polarization $\mathbf P$) on a point charge $q$ as
$$\mathbf F=\frac{q}{c}\;\mathbf v \times\mathbf B=\frac{q}{c}\;\mathbf v \times\mathbf H$$
it does not matter if we use $\mathbf B$ or $\mathbf H$.

For more details on what the equation looks like in matter when all fields ($\mathbf M,\mathbf E,\mathbf H,\mathbf P$) are present, see Eq. 14a of https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3383 (M. Mansuripur, A.R. Zakharian 2013).

Note that in gaussian-cgs units, $\mathbf B$, $\mathbf H$ and $\mathbf M$ could be measured in the same units, sadly this is not often the case. Due to historical reasons, $\mathbf B$ is measured in gauss, $\mathbf H$ in oersted and $\mathbf M$ in emu/cm$^3$, with weird conversion units in between.